# How to resolve "The site can't be reached" on laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-8

My larvel site working fine sometimes. but suddenly it shows "site can't be reached error". after i restartd the server again it is working fine. i checked with my log file, it shows below detail

[image]

i could not find the actual problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code/error here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, you're only showing lines 45-58 of the trace, the really important information is at the start of the trace.

Comment: Well you should post the error message before the #1 line of the laravel log.

Comment: image updated @brance

Comment: The error is `Undefined offset 1` but without the code that is causing the error I cannot help you. Try to see what is in that file on line 495 and post some part of it here.

Comment: Apparently a compiled view has an error. Open up that file listed in line 1 (the one in storage/framework/views) in an editor, and look for 495. Figure out which view that is, and then fix whatever is causing the `undefined offset 1` error